# How to store symbolic matrix in Octave?

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, octave, symbolic-math

In the code below I try to store the 8 symbolic matrix in `MatRot`:

```
MatRot = zeros(4,4,8);

pkg load symbolic

theta = sym('theta',[1 8]);
d = sym('d',[1 8]);
alpha = sym('alpha',[1 8]);
a = sym ('a',[1 8]);

for i=1:8 
    MatRot(:,:,i) = [[cos(theta(1,i)), -cos(alpha(1,i))*sin(theta(1,i)), sin(alpha(1,i))*sin(theta(1,i)), a(1,i)*cos(theta(1,i))];
          [sin(theta(1,i)), cos(alpha(1,i))*cos(theta(1,i)), -sin(alpha(1,i))*cos(theta(1,i)), a(1,i)*sin(theta(1,i))];
          [0, sin(alpha(1,i)), cos(alpha(1,i)), d(1,i)];
          [0, 0, 0, 1]];
end
```

But Octave gives me the next error:

```
error: operator =: no conversion for assignment of 'class' to indexed 'matrix'
error: called from
    SymbolicMatRot at line 14 column 17
```

I found that in MATLAB I can create Symbolic Multidimensional Arrays like this:

```
A = sym('a',[2 2 2])
A(:,:,1) =
[ a1_1_1, a1_2_1]
[ a2_1_1, a2_2_1]
A(:,:,2) =
[ a1_1_2, a1_2_2]
[ a2_1_2, a2_2_2]
```

But Octave gives this error:

```
error: Cannot create symbolic matrix with that size
error: called from
    assert at line 94 column 11
    make_sym_matrix at line 23 column 3
    sym at line 328 column 9
```

I don't know another form to store this.
I'm using Win7 with GNU Octave Version: 4.4.1 and Symbolic version 2.7.1

Comment: I guess by storing its 2D slices.

Comment: and how would it be? @Adriaan

Comment: You could try hardcoding all eight slices, or storing them into a struct/cell array

Comment: I do not know how to work with that @Adriaan

Comment: Coding all the slices it's inefficient but but if there is no other way I imagine that I will do so @Adriaan

Comment: Using a cell array seems a good workaround to me